# Does $ \ddot{x}(t) + (\omega_0)^2 \cdot \arctan(x(t)) = 0 $ have only periodic solutions?

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

Are all the solutions of the following ODE: $ \ddot{x}(t) + (\omega_0)^2 \cdot \arctan(x(t)) = 0 $ periodic for $ \omega_0 = 1.947 \cdot 10^9 $ ?  And if so, how can I proof that this is so?

Comment: Hint: $\omega_0$ is a distraction. How can you get rid of it?

Comment: It can be squared, but I have used the symbol $ \omega_0 $ to avoid the ugly number $ (1.947 \cdot 10^9)^2 $. I expect the exact value to not matter for my question anyway.

Comment: If you set $u=x,v=x'$ you can study the corresponding system $$u'=v,v'=-\omega_0^2 \arctan(u)$$ You can show that orbits to this system are level sets of $$(u,v)\rightarrow \omega_0^2\big(u\arctan(u)-\frac{1}{2}\ln(u^2+1)\big)+\frac{v^2}{2}$$ If your level sets form closed curves that don't contain any equilibrium points of your system, then you are done.

Comment: This looks like an energy argument in disguise where $ \omega_0^2 (u \arctan(u) - \frac{1}{2} \ln(u^2 + 1)) $ stands for the potential energy of a mass point and $ \frac{v^2}{2} $ stands for its kinetic energy...

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

$$
\omega_0^2\left(x \tan ^{-1}(x)-\frac{1}{2} \log \left(x^2+1\right)\right)+\frac{y^2}{2}=C_0
$$

which is a movement constant, has periodic orbits with $\omega_0 = 1.947 \cdot 10^9$ as can be depicted in the attached plot. Note that $x \tan ^{-1}(x)\ge 0$ is even and for small $|x|$ we have $\frac{1}{2} \log \left(x^2+1\right)\approx 0$. In fact, for small $|x|$ we have  $x \tan ^{-1}(x)-\frac{1}{2} \log \left(x^2+1\right)= \frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^4)$ and we have the oscillator $\omega_0^2 x^2+\dot x^2=C_1$.

For big $|x|$ we have that $(x \tan ^{-1}(x)-\frac{1}{2} \log \left(x^2+1\right))'=\tan ^{-1}(x)$ which is a monotonic increasing function so even at big $|x|$ we have

$$
\omega_0^2 g(x) + \frac{y^2}{2} = C_0
$$

with $g(x)$ such that $g(0)=0,g(x)\gt 0\ \forall x\ne 0$ asymptotically linear increasing.

```
w = 1.947 10^9
ContourPlot[1/2 y^2 + w^2 (ArcTan[x] x - 1/2 Log[1 + x^2]), {x, -1, 1}, {y, -10^9, 10^9}, ContourShading -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice picture, which program did you use to draw it?

Comment: The included script is in MATHEMATICA.

Comment: Thank you all. :-)